# (C) Integer Calculator capable of Cancel and Quit

Tags: c, integer, calculator

I am quite new to coding and am supposed to program an integer calculator. I have got it all set up so far but need to be able to quit the program by typing a word beginning with "q" at any time. I also need to be able to cancel the program, i.e. start a new calculation by typing any word beginning with "c".
Code is this

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>
int main()  {
    int running = 1;
    while (running==1) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int r = 0;
    char o;
    printf("*****INTEGER CALCULATOR*****\n\n\n");
    printf("enter x: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("enter y: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
    printf("+ - * / %% : ");
    scanf("%s",&o);
    if (o == '+') {
        r = x+y;
    }
    else if (o == '-')  {
        r = x-y;
    }
    else if(o == '*')   {
        r = x*y;
    }
    else if(o == '/')   {
        if (x==0&&y==0) {
            printf("UNDEFINED\n");
        }
        else if(y==0)   {
            printf("ERROR: DIVISION BY ZERO\n");
        }
        else    {
            r= x/y;
        }
    }
    else if(o == '%')   {
        r= x%y;
    }
    else    {
        printf("OPERATOR ERROR\n");
    }
    printf("Operation: %c\n",o);
    printf("RESULT: %d\n\n\n",r);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: You could modify that `while(running == 1)`, to something like `while(ok == 'c')` or `while(ok != 'q')` or (even if it has no sense to do it like this) `while(ok != q && ok == c)` , and read `ok` after printing the result. To be able to start a new calculation or quit AT ANY TIME, that's a whole another story.

Comment: BTW `include <stdio.h>` -> `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: You have to learn about linux programming atleast basics for this..

Comment: it seems like there is a need to switch to a method for parsing 
enter indirectly as a string instead of  enter the direct number as `scanf("%d",&x);`

Comment: What about 2 + 3 + 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program edited to suit your needs. Everything new is explained in the comments in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // Don't forget # before include!
int main()  {
    char ch = NULL; //character for storing 'q' or 'c'
    do{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int r = 0;
    char o;
    printf("*****INTEGER CALCULATOR*****\n\n\n");
    printf("enter x: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("enter y: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("%d %d\n",x,y);
    printf("+ - * / %% : ");
    scanf(" %c",&o);   //%c not %s as o is a char
    if (o == '+')
        r = x+y;
    else if (o == '-')
        r = x-y;
    else if(o == '*')
        r = x*y;
    else if(o == '/')
    {
        if (x==0&&y==0) {
            printf("UNDEFINED\n");
        }
        else if(y==0)   {
            printf("ERROR: DIVISION BY ZERO\n");
        }
        else    {
            r= x/y;
        }
    }
    else if(o == '%')
        r= x%y;
    else    {
        printf("OPERATOR ERROR! Try again:\n");
    }
    printf("Operation: %c\n",o);
    printf("RESULT: %d\n\n\n",r);

    while(1)  //infinite loop
    {
        printf("Enter 'c' for calculating once more and q to exit");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch=='c' || ch=='q') // if input is c or q
            break;             //break out of infinite loop
        else                   // if input is not c or q
            printf("Invalid option.Try again\n");//print this and continue the infinite loop
    }
    //ch is now sure to be either c or q when execution reaches here
    }while(ch!='q'); // loop until ch is not q
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep matters simple I would use **gets() or **getChar()** functions to read into a variable and process by performing conditional check for desired value.